# How do I change cell array to numeric values in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to the do the following

Input: (cell array)

> ab
>
> ac
>
> ad
>
> aab
>
> ac
>
> aac
>
> aab
>
> ac

I want the output to map to unique numeric values, like

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 2
>
> 5
>
> 4
>
> 2

Is there an easy way to do this?
The input is about 250,000 and of variable length. I just want to map the cells with the same content to the same number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we call your cell array A, then the following command does what you need:

```
[uniqueCells,~,idxYouWant] = unique(A);
```

In this, the `uniqueCells` are the unique values you have (in sorted order); and `idxYouWant` is an array of numbers like you want, where

```
A = uniqueCells(idxYouWant);
```

I think this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Damn. How did I miss this? Thank you so much. 
I must have used used 'unique' not less than a hundred times.

Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Using the third argument was something I needed to google... and I've used `unique` at least 200 times. :-) It's funny how you used the word "unique" in your question. Sometimes the answer is just hiding in plain sight. We all do it.